# Objective C UIViewController Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a UIViewController to which I've added a label, a button, a tableView and a searchView.  I call this `locationTableView` in my system

I then have another viewController called `mapTabBarController` which when the user clicks on a button I call this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];    
locationTableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocationTableViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:locationTableView.view];
```

I disable the `status bar` and the `navigation bar` as the `location view` is a direct overlay on the screen but still displays our `mapTabBar`

I am working with the cancel button currently, which really just hides the `locationTableView` and turns the navigationbar and the status bar back to being displayed.  I originally tried to get this working just the standard way of having

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: NO];
    [self.view removeFomSuperview];
}
```

This worked, but then I couldn't figure out how to get the navigationBar to re-display.  So I thought of creating a delegate to do it, so I began working on that:

LocationTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class LocationTableViewController;
@protocol LocationTableViewControllerDelegate;

@interface LocationTableViewController : UIViewController

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *locationTableView;
    - (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id) sender;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) id<LocationTableViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end

@protocol LocationTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) LocationTableViewcontroller:(LocationTableViewController *)viewController cancelButtonPressed:(CGFloat)value;

@end
```

LocationTableViewController.m

```
#import "LocationTableViewController.h"

@interface LocationTableViewController ()
{
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
}
@end

@implementation LocationTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self navigationController].delegate = self;
    searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
    [searchBar setFrame: CGRectMake(8, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 50)];
    [searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [self.locationTableView addSubview:searchBar];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    id<LocationTableViewControllerDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    [strongDelegate LocationTableViewcontroller:self cancelButtonPressed:0.0f];
}
@end
```

Then instantiated it in my MapTabBarController.m

```
@interface MapTabBarController () <FPPopoverControllerDelegate, PrivacyPopoverDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, LocationTableViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

and I created the function for it:

```
- (void)LocationTableViewcontroller:(LocationTableViewController *)viewController cancelButtonPressed:(CGFloat)value {
    NSLog(@"We Clicked the Cancel Button!");
}
```

Problem that I'm having with this, is that it is never called - I have no NSLog in the console.  Not sure what I've done wrong with this so need a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do When creating locationTableView

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];    
locationTableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocationTableViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:locationTableView.view];

// Add this line

locationTableView.delegate = mapTabBarController
```

Comment: Works like a dream.  I had actually just figured this out prior to coming back and seeing your answer.  Since your answer and my solution are identical, I've selected it as the correct answer and giving upvote.